# If $|z| < 1$, show that $|\operatorname{Arg} \frac{1 + z}{1 − z}| < \frac\pi2$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $|z| < 1$, show that
$$\bigg|\operatorname{Arg} \frac{1 + z}{1 − z}\bigg| < \frac\pi2$$

I know how to solve this using the properties but i wanted to try geometric methods.
But for some reasons, I got the exact opposite answer and still i can't understand where is wrong.

Here is my solution.

[image: my solution]

Just in case if the image is not clear, it says

Let $z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}$.
$|z|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<1\implies x^2+y^2<1,$ so the point is in the circle where the center is $(0,0)$ and $r=1.$

$$\operatorname{Arg}\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=\arg(1+z)-\arg(1-z)+2k\pi, \ \ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

$\arg(1+z)$ is the angle between real axis and $(-1,0)\sim(x,y)$ (let's say A)
$\arg(1-z)$ is the angle between real axis and $(1,0)\sim (x,y)$ (let's say B)

Then I have to prove $A-B<\pi/2$

And then I draw the complex plane.

Since $(x,y)$ is in the circle, the triangle with $(1,0),(-1,0),(x,y)$ is obtuse triangle.

Thus, $A+(\pi-B)<\pi /2\implies A-B<-\pi/2,$ which seems the opposite.

I'm new to complex field/plane so it's hard to get the fallacy here.
Can you guys help me?
Thank you

Comment: Be careful with the direction!  $1-z$ goes from $z$ to $1$ not $1$ to $z$, so $\arg(1-z)=\theta'-\pi$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is maybe a simpler approach. Note

$$w=\frac{1+z}{1-z} = \frac{1-|z|^2 + (z-\bar z)}{|1-z|^2}
$$

Thus, $Re (w)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|1-z|^2}>0$, which leads to
$$|\text{Arg}(w)| <\frac\pi2$$

Comment: yeah i knew how to solve it with that but i wanted to try another method. Thank you for your help :)